# Timeout doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am trying to run function with timeout. The following works right on Chrome, but on Firefox the `rd` function doesn't run at all. What am I doing wrong?

```
function readenter(e) {
  var t = setTimeout(function() {
    rd(e);
  }, parseFloat(delay)*1000);
}
function rd(e) {
  var id = e.target.id;
  document.getElementById(id).style.border = "thick solid red";     
}
```

Comment: Are you sure readenter is being called? Show the code that calls it our that sets the handler.

Comment: Where does the value `delay` come from? Are you sure that the `rd` function is not called, or could it be that the `e.target` value doesn't survive until it is called?

Comment: Yes, checked both those things by adding textnodes on the start of readenter and rd, the readenter worked but rd not

Comment: And the delay also valid..

Comment: And it works right on chrome!

Comment: Did you check the console for any errors?

Comment: I cheked with validator.w3 and it shown no errors or wornings.

Comment: Just checked and it shows: ReferenceError: event is not defined